# Keycloak 23.x call a webhook after email verification

Tags: keycloak, hook, keycloak-services

I have a KC server used by several clients one of them registers users using REST API and I wish this app being called when the user gets back to KC after email verification.

I guess the best option would be having KC call a webhook in my service, how can I achieve it ?
Is there a module or plugin to use ?
Should I implement a custom action in the flow ?
Which is the most Keycloakish approach ?